# my queries insert data in phpmyadmin but does not insert from my app in php

Tags: php, mysql

i wrote 3 queries ,that must insert data in 3 tables in one time...
it works in mysql(phpmyadmin).... correctly and inserted data.
but when i write this program in php it does not work...
it makes me crazy . please help me ...
my query

```
INSERT INTO `deliverydatetimetable`(`DeliveryId`,`Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, `Minutes`, `Second`) VALUES ('$DeliveryId','','','','','','');
                                  INSERT INTO `deliverylocationtable`(`DeliveryId`,`DeliveryLatitude`, `DeliveryLongitude`, `RequestId`, `Accepted`, `DeliveryAddress`) VALUES ('$DeliveryId','','','','','');
                                  INSERT INTO `deliveryworkstatetable`(`DeliveryId`,`IsBusy`) VALUES ('$DeliveryId','');
```

php codes

```
function activateRelatedTables(){
$connection=createConnection();
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$DeliveryId=$obj->DeliveryId;
$result=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `deliverydatetimetable`(`DeliveryId`,`Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, `Minutes`, `Second`) VALUES ('$DeliveryId','','','','','','');
                                  INSERT INTO `deliverylocationtable`(`DeliveryId`,`DeliveryLatitude`, `DeliveryLongitude`, `RequestId`, `Accepted`, `DeliveryAddress`) VALUES ('$DeliveryId','','','','','');
                                  INSERT INTO `deliveryworkstatetable`(`DeliveryId`,`IsBusy`) VALUES ('$DeliveryId','');");
echo json_encode(array('Result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_query` only accepts 1 query. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: What does `mysqli_error($connection)` tell you?  Also note that your code is wide open to SQL injection, users can execute whatever SQL code they want on your server.

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Also instead of columns `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, `Minutes`, `Second`. Why not use 1 datetime column?

Comment: i need some of date time for example  day or month or minute lonly

Comment: You could use `day()`, `minute()`, `month()` etc. As individual columns you're going to need to concat in the future to have a full date.

Comment: thanks all, mysqli_multi_query worked for me...:)